# Is there a way to make moving/changing shadows on Scenekit (like a rising sun)?

Tags: objective-c, swift, shader, scenekit, scnlight

my basic code is pretty much this on that tutorial:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-scenekit-fundamentals--cms-23847

I want to make a sunrise behaviour. Something like the lightNode begins on the same height as the constrained cubeNode and move it up so that the shadow shall become smaller over time.
Therefore I tried to move the nodes via SCNAction.move(to...).

Action on lightNode -> nothing happens

Action on the constrained cubeNode -> shadow starts to flicker, but no changing

I tried around with the shadowModes. I think I misunderstood this. No useful results came up.

Has anyone an idea if scenekit supports something like dynamicly changing shadows?

Comment: Please show us what you so-call a rising sun looks like in a picture.

Comment: Here I found a video that shows the shadow moving effect I want to create with Scenekit:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=305b3X_FDZM

Comment: After view the said YouTube video, I have more questions than an answer.  Now, I'm not sure what part in video you want to create with a cube.  Additionally, when you say "Action on lightNode -> nothing happens," it's hard for one to say anything since you show no line of code.  Without additional information, I propose that this topic be closed.

Comment: It is like in the code in the linked description. It is just about the question:
When you put a spotlight somewhere into the SCNScene, is it possible to move the spotlight in a way that shadows are dynamically changed.

It is just a general question. I have nothing found yet on internet. I tried to move spotlights via SCNActions in any combination, either the constraint node or the light node. Nothing worked and I have no clue so far if that is an option what might work at all. So I have nothing to offer or show what might help into the direction..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to make it. My major mistakes were:

1. Somehow it does not work to access the lightNode (it just has no effect, when actions for a `lightNode` are called)
2. I tried to go via `SCNAction.move(to...)`. The answer is to use a rotation instead of a longitudinal movement.

The answer was accessing the constraint Node (instead of the lightNode). In this code the cubeNode is replaced with an invisible `centerPoint` (as the constraint node where the `lightNode` has to look at). A `boxNode`has been added for making a canvas for the shadow. The `lightNode`has to be added to the `centerPoint`, NOT to the scene.

There is the modified `viewDidLoad`-method. If you want to check this out, open Xcode, start a new project as SceneKit Game and replace the `viewDidLoad` with the following code.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // create a new scene
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!

    // create and add a camera to the scene
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

    // place the camera
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)

    // create and add a light to the scene
    let centerPoint = SCNNode.init()
    centerPoint.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(centerPoint)

    let light = SCNLight()
    light.type = SCNLight.LightType.spot
    light.spotInnerAngle = 30
    light.spotOuterAngle = 80
    light.castsShadow = true
    light.color = UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed: 0.95, green: 0.8, blue: 0.8, alpha: 1)
    light.zFar = 200

    let lightNode = SCNNode()
    lightNode.light = light
    lightNode.position = SCNVector3Make(20, 100, 50)

    let constraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: centerPoint)
    constraint.isGimbalLockEnabled = true
    lightNode.constraints = [constraint]
    centerPoint.addChildNode(lightNode)

    let ambientLight = SCNLight.init()
    ambientLight.type = SCNLight.LightType.ambient
    ambientLight.color = UIColor.darkGray

    scene.rootNode.light = ambientLight

    // retrieve the ship node
    let material = SCNMaterial.init()
    material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.yellow
    material.lightingModel = SCNMaterial.LightingModel.phong
    material.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true

    let boxNode = SCNNode.init(geometry: SCNBox.init(width: 10, height: 0.1, length: 10, chamferRadius: 0))
    boxNode.geometry?.firstMaterial = material
    boxNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, -2, 0)

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)

    // animate spot light rotation
    centerPoint.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: CGFloat(M_PI), y: 0, z: CGFloat(M_PI), duration: 5)))

    // animate color light change
    let lightColorChange: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: "color")
    lightColorChange.fromValue = UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed: 0.95, green: 0.8, blue: 0.8, alpha: 1)
    lightColorChange.toValue = UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed: 0, green: 0, blue: 0.4, alpha: 1)
    lightColorChange.duration = 5.0
    lightColorChange.autoreverses = true
    lightColorChange.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    light.addAnimation(lightColorChange, forKey: "changeLight")

    // retrieve the SCNView
    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView

    // set the scene to the view
    scnView.scene = scene

    // allows the user to manipulate the camera
    scnView.allowsCameraControl = true

    // show statistics such as fps and timing information
    scnView.showsStatistics = true

    // configure the view
    scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    // add a tap gesture recognizer
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
    scnView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
```

There is also a color change of the light is considered. With a CABasicAnimation it is possible to change the `light.color`-property over time. It is not like a perfect sunrise with all color steps, but there is also a way to chain those animations to make it more complex. (For this search for "wenderlich how to create a complex loading animation".

But I did not find a way to change the shadow color. It could be a nice effect to have white shadows on nighttime and black shadows on daytime. `light.shadowColor` did not help yet. If someone has an idea it is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can make a beautiful moving shadow. If your spotlight isn't moving it may be because the tutorial had you put a constraint on it. Try removing it.

```
// lightNode.constraints = [constraint]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried this with all light types. With `omni`and `directional`it works when I move the `lightNode`. But it only creates shadows on the surface like this:
http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4657/oajhkka8_png.htm

`ambient` does not give an option for making shadows. And - to be honest - with `spot` I was not able to calibrate the light spot onto the object manually (lol). Without the constraining I have no clue how I can make a right positioning for a spotlight.

But with `spot` you can make this:
http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4657/yh7e52ok_png.htm

Comment: But I noticed that the `SCNAction.move(to...)` brings the wrong effect. But a rotation works very much like the sunrise effect I was looking for. I posted a code where it works.

By the way, do you know to make a better rendering of the shadow spots on the ground? I tried to go with `light.shadowSampleCount = 10`, but the shadow disappeared and the performance of the app became aweful.

Comment: Try setting zNear on the spotlight.